# IF-ELSE Statement erro

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code in which if there is data in the parameter - `arrRecords` then print the data, if there is not data in the parameter `arrRecords` i.e. `arrRecords = ""`, then skip this step and get out.

---

```
If IsEmpty(arrRecords) = True Then
GoTo Get_Out

ElseIf IsEmpty(arrRecords) = Fales Then
PrintArray arrRecords, Y, Lastrecord, 1

End If

Get_Out:
```

---

I am also clearing the data in `arrRecords` after every loop using `arrRecords = ""`. Still in cases where there is data or no data, the code always goes to the statement for Print. Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: I often wonder why people compare True to True to see if it is True. Besides, you didn't declare or assign a value to `Fales`.

Comment: Need to see more of your code.  Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and declare all variables.  That would have prevented the `Fales` typo in your code, among other things.  The obvious answer is that `arrRecords` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

From a general point of view

1. If you have something after the `Then` on the same line you have terminate the If. You will then get a syntax error if you have a following `ElseIf`.
2. Use `Option Explicit` to pick up typos such as `Fales`.
3. You don't need `= True` just  `If IsEmpty(arrRecords)` .
4. You can default into an `Else` if not `True` without a test for `False`
5. Do you need to then `Exit Sub` if `False` or carry on ?
6. What is `arrRecords`? Where is it coming from?

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    If IsEmpty(arrRecords) Then '<> vbNullString   ''if string
        GoTo Get_Out
    Else
        PrintArray arrRecords, Y, Lastrecord, 1  
        'Exit Sub '<== What happens here? Otherwise you still hit Get_Out
    End If

Get_Out:

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the prompt response. I tried this and it still goes to PrintArray. To answer your querry, when it has data it prints the array to a sheet. The data is present in the form of an array in the arrRecords string.

Comment: What is arrRecords? Where is it declared?  If it goes to print array then it is not empty by the test given. So, is it the correct test to apply?

Comment: arrRecords is a string declared at the start of the code, i run a query which connects my code to a database to fill the data in arrRecords in an array from. What other tests do you suggest could be used here?

Comment: <>vbNullString ? So is it a string or an array?

Comment: What i was doing wrong was treating the string wrong, i was using the wrong character type and it fixed my error

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Remember to post as answer so future readers can learn.

Comment: No worries, just returned from vacation and updated this